# How do I change the colour of a button when hovering over it?

Tags: html, css, windows, visual-studio, hex

I know this question has probably been asked many times but i've seen some answers and don't really understand. Basically I want to change the colour of a button when hovering over it. Here is my CSS code and the class name I used.

```html
.ButtonClass{
    width:190px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background:#6aa404;
    border:none;
    z-index:100;
    padding:7px 15px 8px 15px;
    font-weight:800;
    font-style:normal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ButtonClass:hover {  
  background-color: #ccc; /*button color*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does that go as a separate class and how would that be placed into my html?

Comment: if you have your css in a .css file, under the class you posted, in the same file. otherwise in the <style> tag if you are defining your css in the html file

Comment: @matt, simply put it in your CSS beneath your `.ButtonClass` block. This is a so-called pseudo-class. Another note @RVandersteen: that’s not how CSS comments work…